# Adding credentials to my simple PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell

I have this PowerShell script that will grab the modified date of a file on a remote Windows PC.  The remote PC has a local username and password I need to get the script to work.

When I run the script I get a prompt to add the username and password which I know works (tried in Explorer) but I get the error below:

**Script**

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
$ServerName = Get-Content "c:\temp\devices.txt"
$Output = foreach ($Server in $ServerName) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        $Credential = Get-Credential
        Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$Server\c$\ProgramData\sync\data.xml" -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
$Output | Out-File c:\temp\dataxml.csv
```

**error**

[image]

Ideally I'd like to add the username and password to a file and get no prompt.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) has no `-Credential` parameter. To target a file system on another machine (that isn't accessible via a UNC path), you'll need a form of _remoting_, such as via [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)

Comment: _"Ideally I'd like to add the username and password to a file and get no prompt"_  Sounds like a security breach waiting to happen.

Comment: Yeah storing the password in the file is a really bad idea. Ideally if your wanting this to work unattended, and you have Active Directory, would be to create a service account, that has access to the servers, and the service account is setup to run the powershell, that way no credentials are required in the script.